# Autolayout For Subviews of UITableViewCell not works well

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

In `UITabelViewCell` ,there is a problem when i add a `UIView` and `UILabel`.
The `UILabel` has dynamic height, and `UIView` has a fixed Rect, i think.
first of all, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` for both of them,
and label's `preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 280`, and `numberOfLines = 0`.

Constraints ,as follows:

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"_label":self.label,@"_view":self.view};

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[_label]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[_view]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[_label(100@300)]-[_view(20)]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
```

when finished, the label has only one line, and there are some exceptions:

```
 (
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8cdb450 V:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x8cda6e0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x8cd9e40 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8cdb530 V:[UIView:0x8cda930(20)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8cdb560 V:[UIView:0x8cda930]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x8cd9e40 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8cdb100 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x8cd9e40(44)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8a88de0 V:[UILabel:0x8cda6e0]-(NSSpace(8))-[UIView:0x8cda930]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8a88de0 V:[UILabel:0x8cda6e0]-(NSSpace(8))-[UIView:0x8cda930]>
```

Comment: why are you adding constraints for self.view?

Comment: Are you setting the cell height appropriately (table delegate)?

Comment: @Levi thank you for your reply, but i just add them for Cell's contentView

Comment: @Wain thank you, certainly, i just put text in label,and call [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded]; [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

Comment: Yes, but the delegate still tells the table view what height each row should be, and if the table sets the height too short then you will have unattainable constraints...

Comment: @Wain oh , i got your point ,yes, i implement the `delegate(heightForRowAtIndexPath)` by those codes.